# Copy coloured font rows from multiple Excel tabs into final tab on same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have tabs in an Excel document (e.g. 580400 / 580401 / 580402 / 580403).

Some of the entry lines in each tab have conditional formatting to turn some of the lines blue.

I am trying to copy all the blue font lines to another tab called "Sheet2" within the same workbook.

I made this work on one tab (580400).

How do I include the other tabs (580401 / 580402 / 580403)?

```vb
Sub CopyColouredFontTransactions()

Dim PeriodField As Range
Dim PeriodCell As Range
Dim Sheet1WS As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2WS As Worksheet

Dim x As Long

Set Sheet1WS = Worksheets("580400")
Set PeriodField = Sheet1WS.Range("A2", Sheet1WS.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set Sheet2WS = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For Each PeriodCell In PeriodField

    If PeriodCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then
        
        PeriodCell.Resize(1, 15).Copy Destination:= _
          Sheet2WS.Range("A1").Offset(Sheet2WS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            
    End If

Next PeriodCell

Sheet2WS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: If font is set using conditional formatting, `PeriodCell.Font.Color` will not see the color. You will need to use `PeriodCell.DisplayFormat.Font.Color` to get the color that was applied using conditional formatting

Comment: Try looping trough each sheet?

Answer (score 0):

you could try add a for next loop that will iterate an array of worksheets name. See example below (not tested)

```
Sub CopyColouredFontTransactions()
Dim PeriodField As Range
Dim PeriodCell As Range
Dim Sheet1WS As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2WS As Worksheet

Dim x As Long

Set Sheet2WS = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim tabs As Variant
Set tabs = Array("580400", "580401", "580403")

Dim tabname As String

For Each tabname In tabs
    Set Sheet1WS = Worksheets(tabname)
    Set PeriodField = Sheet1WS.Range("A2", Sheet1WS.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    For Each PeriodCell In PeriodField
        If PeriodCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then
            PeriodCell.Resize(1, 15).Copy Destination:= _
            Sheet2WS.Range("A1").Offset(Sheet2WS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next PeriodCell
Next tabs

Sheet2WS.Columns.AutoFit
```

End Sub